# how to fit the pop up in application

Tags: apache-flex

I am opening a pop up within a application and problem is that this popup window is not opening correctly when i want to open popup at the end of the application that means popup height decreases and some data truncated in popup window .I am using canvas for pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the popup using Point Object.Set the titlewindow's width and height to fit the contents.

```
            var titleWin:FileUpload=PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, PopupName, true) as FileUpload;
            var point:Point=new Point(0, 0);

            point=this.parentDocument.parent.localToGlobal(point);
            titleWin.x=point.x + 100;
            titleWin.y=point.y + 100;
            titleWin.width=500;
            titleWin.height=400;
```

Refer [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=15_Geometry_3.html) link to read about Point object.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [PopUpManager.centerPopUp()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#centerPopUp%28%29) function.